# Type checking a recursive single argument and single output function [Ocaml]

Tags: recursion, ocaml

```
let rec loop (x:?) : ? =
  loop loop
```

Is there any types replacing the `?` that will allow this function, `loop`, to type check?

Answer (score 4):

If you supply `-rectypes` to the interpreter it will tell you the type of your function:

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let rec loop x = loop loop;;
val loop : 'a -> 'b as 'a = <fun>
```

You can declare this function using separate type variables for the parameter and return types, but this seems (to me) to be the same as not specifying the types.

```
# let rec loop (x: 'a) : 'b = loop loop;;
val loop : 'a -> 'b as 'a = <fun>
```

If you don't allow recursive types (with `-rectypes`), the function can't be made to typecheck because its type is recursive.